# Google in app implementation for multiple activities

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I have an Android application, and I wanted to implement purchase through the Google in app process.
I have implemented it and it works, but I have multiple activities which user can purchase from, so I thought about "base activity" that implement the in app process and all other activities will extend from it, I'm not sure it's the best idea, I need an indication for the status of the purchase and so on...

May someone has a better solution or I might implement the whole process separately for each activity?

Thank you
Eliran

Comment: Please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thank, I would like to implement the "Google in app" process in my application. I have the main activity which the purchase can be made from there, I also have some other activities that the purchase can be made from those. I don't want to implement the whole purchase process in my main activity and in my all other activities, I prefer to find a way for implementing it in one class or object, that all the activities that might use the purchase process can use it. Hope it more specific :)

Comment: You could move the purchase process into a service, using an AIDL interface to communicate.  The activities would then use a common API to make a purchase.  This API could take an AIDL callback as a parameter that will be called when a purchased is completed to notify the calling activity.